# comparison of sets of binary sequences

Tags: binary-data, biostatistics

I want to compare three sets of binary sequences and assess whether they differ statistically.  Each sequence is 100 bits long (the length 0-100 represents the axis of an  elongated tissue : if there is a 1 at position i, it means that a cell from that particular lineage was found at this position). The sets contain 26, 20 and 29 sequences respectively. Each set comes from a different pool of cells and I want to know whether the 3 pools differ significantly as far as their capacity to colonize along the tissue is concerned.

Comment: How do you measure "capacity to colonize"? Is it number of '1' cells? Or particular cells? Or what?

Comment: We are able to mark different pools of ancestor-cells and want to compare their respective contribution to the developing tissue. For instance we ask whether cells descending from an ancestor located in the proximal part of the nascent tissue are found over the whole length of the fully-developed tissue ? Each sequence describes the observation of a clone, i.e. a group of cells sharing the same ancestor. For any such group, we monitor the positions of the cells along the axis: we put a 1 in a particular position if a cell is present and a 0 if no cell is present.